# Downloading bugzilla bug as xml file - size of file

Tags: python, integration, bugzilla

I've written a python client for Buzgilla which is using urllib.requests to download bugs as XML files. XML files are returned by parameterized show_bug.cgi interface but.

A lot of issues in our bugzilla has many many attachments (some are just deleted but still visible) - so downloaded XML files are huge - they're a 100 - 300 Mb :(

Is there any way to download bug as XML file without attachments encoded as Base64 text?

Comment: didn't you use python built-in module for bugzilla? this post lacks some supplementary details.

Comment: Well if not, you can use module python-bugzilla straight forth, if it's not your convenience, use `xmlrpc.cgi` interface instead of `show_bug`, then you can filter your requirements by choosing `bug` or `comments` or `attachments` each one of its own, if the response header is json convert it to xml. [see here](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/api/index.html)